# write list to CSV

Tags: python, list, csv, fwrite

I have a list of lists like:

```
[[A], [B], [A,B], [B], [C], [A, B, C], [C, A]]
```

I want to write it to CSV file like:

```
A,
B,
A,B,
B,
C,
A,B,C,
C,A,
```

Please consider that I have 556,375 lists and each of them contains minimum 20 variables.

Comment: A csv line like `A,` has two values, `A` and `''` (An empty string).  Is this intentional?

Comment: Sure, use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. Your list appears to be in perfect format for it.

Comment: You can use the `csv` module, or my personal favorite `pandas`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add the extra comma, just add an empty cell at the end of each row.

Here's a short way using generator comprehension within `writerows`

```
import csv

l = [["A"], ["B"], ["A","B"], ["B"], ["C"], ["A", "B", "C"], ["C", "A"]]

with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f:  # open("output.csv","wb") for Python 2
    cw = csv.writer(f)
    cw.writerows(r+[""] for r in l)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
file = open("myFile.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ",")
for list_ in myList:
     writer.writerow(list_)
file.close()
```

Comment: `file` is a builtin, at least in Python 2, so you should avoid using that as a variable name. Also, you should use a context manager (`with`) to open files. Finally, are you sure you meant `writerows` and not `writerow`, since you're iterating the list with each element representing a row? Does that add the trailing comma?

Comment: The delimiter can be changed to whatever and yes it trials although it depends on what i open the .csv with. i ran it with writerows and writerow and both gave same output (although i was using a tuple instead)

Comment: In this case, I think `writerows` only works because you put the single item in a list as you iterate. You can use `writerow` without placing `list_` in a list, and use `writerows` to write a nested list in one go, without iterating.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add new line (\n) at the end of the rows:

```
lista = [['A'], ['B'], ['A','B'], ['B'], ['C'], ['A','B','C'], ['C','A']]
f = open('lista.csv','a')
i = 0
while (i<len(lista)):   
    f.write(str(lista[i])+"\n")
    i = i + 1
f.close()
```